# How to get only parent product with pagination using Magento2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, category-products

I need to fetch only the parent products as per category ID using magento2 end point but as per my code I am getting also the children products. I am explaining my code below.

```
$quoteUrl ='https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id& searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2& searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[pageSize]=8& searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&&searchCriteria[sortOrders][1][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC';
$chQuote = curl_init($quoteUrl);
curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$quote = json_decode(curl_exec($chQuote));
$array = json_decode(json_encode($quote), True);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Here I am getting also the children product but I need only the parent products of `Category ID 2`. The result should same what the below `end points` returns with pagination.

```
$quoteUrl ='https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/2/products';
```

The above API returns the parent product only so my requirement is I need to add the pagination to this `API's` result.

Comment: by parent product you mean only config, or also simple that are not variant of configurable product?

Comment: @KonradSiamro: Actually I need the result of `https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/2/products` with pagination and also Both API returnin different result.

Comment: I know, but You wrote You dont want get children produyct. By wrting children product You mean all simple that are attached to configurable as variant, right? You can use search criteria and add `visibility` as 4 (it means visible on catalog, search)

Comment: @KonradSiamro: I need config and also simple which has no children product only.

Comment: @KonradSiamro: I think visibility=4 giving the right result.

Comment: Jup, in that case visibility = 4 will works. Glad to help You ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107875/discussion-between-subhraedqart-and-konrad-siamro).